# Ansible - long list as variable - dynamic list

Tags: ansible

newbie with ansible

how do i pass a dynamic list of values in ansible

i want to initially keep this as 8

- "{{ [ 'lun1' , 'lun2' , 'lun3' , 'lun4' , 'lun5' , 'lun6' ,'lun7' , 'lun8' ] }} "

but later increase it to 50 , 100

```
  - name: Create object
    na
      state: present
      name: "{{ hostvars[item[1]]['iscsi_hostname']['stdout'] }}{{item[0]}}"
      flexvol_name: "{{ vol_name }}{{ hostvars[item[1]]['iscsi_hostname']['stdout'] }}"
      hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    with_nested:
       - "{{ [ 'lun1' , 'lun2' , 'lun3' , 'lun4' , 'lun5' , 'lun6' ,'lun7' , 'lun8' ] }} "
       - "{{ groups['redhat'] }}"
```

so i wanted

- "{{ [ 'lun1' , 'lun2' , 'lun3' , 'lun4' , 'lun5' , 'lun6' ,'lun7' , 'lun8' ] }} "

as

- "{{ [ 'lun1' , 'lun2' , 'lun3' , 'lun4' , 'lun5' , 'lun6' ,'lun7' , 'lun8' ........ 'lun50' ] }} "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list var dynamically with `set_fact` and `with_sequence` using a variable with the `number` of size you need. And send the `number` with `--extra-vars`.

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
  - name: Create list var
    set_fact
      my_list: "{{ my_list | default ([]) }} + ['lun{{ item }}']"
    with_sequence: start=1 end={{ number }}

  - name: Create object
    na
      state: present
      name: "{{ hostvars[item[1]]['iscsi_hostname']['stdout'] }}{{item[0]}}"
      flexvol_name: "{{ vol_name }}{{ hostvars[item[1]]['iscsi_hostname']['stdout'] }}"
      hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    with_nested:
       - "{{ my_list }} "
       - "{{ groups['redhat'] }}"
```

Example of commands to execute your `playbook.yml`

```yaml
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "number=10"
```

```yaml
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "number=25"
```

```yaml
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "number=50"
```